# Conditional calling using static factory method

Tags: java, constructor, overloading, static-factory

This is my project structure. I'm trying to use a static factory function to check for an object and then perform some operations. I followed the this process.

**Parent Class:**

```
public abstract class Parent {

    protected static Child1DTO ch1;
    protected static Child2DTO ch2;

    public Parent(Child1DTO ch1) {
        this.ch1 = ch1;
    }

    public Parent(Child2DTO ch2) {
        this.ch2 = ch2;
    }

    protected Parent() {

    }

    public static Child1DTO getCh1() {
        return ch1;
    }

    public static Child2DTO getCh2() {
        return ch2;
    }

    public static Class<?> childType(Object obj) {

        if (obj instanceof Child1DTO) {
                    //do something
            return Child1DTO.class;
        } else if (obj instanceof Child2DTO) {
                    //do something
            return Child2DTO.class;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Child1DTO Class**:

```
public class Child1DTO extends Parent {

    private String fName1;
    private String lName1;

    public String getfName1() {
        return fName1;
    }
    public void setfName1(String fName1) {
        this.fName1 = fName1;
    }
    public String getlName1() {
        return lName1;
    }
    public void setlName1(String lName1) {
        this.lName1 = lName1;
    }
}
```

**Child2DTO Class:**

```
public class Child2DTO extends Parent{

    private String fName2;
    private String lName2;

    public String getfName2() {
        return fName2;
    }
    public void setfName2(String fName2) {
        this.fName2 = fName2;
    }
    public String getlName2() {
        return lName2;
    }
    public void setlName2(String lName2) {
        this.lName2 = lName2;
    }
}
```

**Child Class:**

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    public Child(Child1DTO ch1) {
        super(ch1);
    }

    public Child(Child2DTO ch2) {
        super(ch2);
    }

    public static Child test(Object obj) {

        if (obj instanceof Child1DTO) { //is this the correct way to check?
            //do something
            return new Child((Child1DTO) obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof Child2DTO) {//is this the correct way to check?

            //do something
            return new Child((Child2DTO) obj);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        if(childType(ch1).equals(ch1)){
            //do something
        }else if(childType(ch2).equals(ch2)){
            //do something
        }else{
            System.out.println("Failed!");
        }
  }

}
```

**EDIT:**

`Parent` class has one `Child` class and two DTOs `Child1DTO` and `Child2DTO`.

1. Do I need to implement conditional check in Parent class or Child class?
2. How to achieve conditional check with constructors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) If you think it is not a duplicate then tell us which exact object is null and where exactly you thought it got a value.

Comment: My main issue is to achieve conditional calling. If that can be achieved, there won't be any NPE.

Comment: "_My main issue is to achieve conditional calling_" If you fix the NPE then maybe your "conditional calling" will work correctly.

Comment: What csmckelvey wants to point out is that you must find the object that you are accessing before instantiate it (ch1? :)) But the fact that you cannot see that show that you must improve your language knowledge and debugging skill first. And the stack trace coukd have bring you at the exact point ;)

Comment: Rookie mistake guys! @csmckelvey Updated the question.